# Avoid execution of AsyncTask when ViewPager is slided fast

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, jsoup

I'm using a `ViewPager` to show content fetched from a website with jsoup.
In the `onCreateView` of each page I call an `AsyncTask` that fetches the data and updates the `View` for each page.

The problem is that when the user slides the pages faster than usual the `AsyncTask` is called several times and, consequently, several useless requisitions are made with jsoup, since the only useful is the last.

I tried using `setUserVisibleHint` on the `Fragment` class and adding `setOnPageChangeListener` in the `Activity` class but these methods make me lose the `ViewPager` behaviour of preloading the next page and I don't want that.

Is there a way to know when the user stopped sliding and only call the `AsynTask` at that moment?

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String PAGE_NUMBER = "page";

    private int mProblemNumber;

    public static ScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber) {
        ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PAGE_NUMBER, pageNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(PAGE_NUMBER);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);
        new GetPageTask(url).execute();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: use a dummy handler.postdelay(..., delay_ms) or countdown timer. 1sec delay should work fine. If you have only a few fragments you can set viewpager.setoffscreenpagelimit(fragments_count) so it will load once and never initialize everytime on page changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be just to check whether the `AsyncTask` is running or not. Store a reference to your `AsyncTask` and then if user scrolls back to this page you can check its status using `AsyncTask.Status` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html).

Also, if you want to avoid starting new tasks when user scrolls too fast, you can use `handler.postDelayed(yourRunnable, longMs)`. Each time user selects a page you can do something like this:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnable);
handler.postDelayed(yourRunnable, longMs);
```

This way you will remove previous pending task and schedule a new one in `longMs` time. E.g. if you put 1000 ms then your tasks will start only in a second after user selected a page.

Comment: As I commented in the other answer `postDelayed` doesn't do what I want because all the slided pages will call the `AsyncTask` after the specified time anyway.
In your first solution, is it possible to check the status of an `AsyncTask` other than the one in the current page? If so, this solution might work.

Comment: Not sure why would you need that, but you can have an array or list of `AsyncTask` and use fragment position to get the instance you need. You can put that array into enclosing fragment / activity.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to delay the request to fetch the content. For instance, if you are swiping quickly, waiting like half a second to load the content (instead of right away) would give the system a chance to breathe and check if the page is still visible.

Something like this:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    if (isVisible){
        new GetPageTask(url).execute();
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but `postDelayed` doesn't do what I want because all the slided pages will call the `AsyncTask` after the specified time anyway.

Comment: Would it?

That's why we check if the fragment is visible. If the fragment is visible after the user swipes through a bunch of views quickly, then the task would run. Otherwise, you swiped past the views too quickly and nothing would happen (because `fragment.isVisible()` would fail).